# Is there any way of copy/pasting, duplicating, or auto-generating posts for fast testing?

Tags: posts

I always find myself creating posts every time to test layout or design.

For example, I create stuff like:

> Content 1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut
>   laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

6 times.

Is there a fast way of copy pasting posts, duplicating them or auto-generating them, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [**Demo Data Creator**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/demo-data-creator/) plugin with it you can create and set:

- Number of users to create
- Number of blogs per user (for WPMU/MultiSite)
- Whether users must have a blog
- Number of categories in each blog
- Number of posts in each blog
- Number of paragraphs in each blog post
- Number of pages in each blog
- Number of top-level pages
- Number of levels to nest pages
- Number of comments per post for each blog
- Number of links in blogroll for each blog

Comment: For anyone interested you can see [the bulk of the code for that plugin here](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/demo-data-creator/trunk/demodata.php), to get a better picture of how it creates and assigns names(random selection from array of values in most cases).

Answer (score 3):

Ehm, [Export/Import](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_SubPanel) them with native functionality? :)

There is also official [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) data with plenty of relevant stuff to go through when checking a theme.

Comment: There's a few invalid paths in that test data, but that's what i use. Not sure specifically which images(was a while ago i installed the test data), but i remember i had to update a few DB entries to get the images to appear(the paths were off)..